# What is the Regular Expression For "Not Whitespace and Not a hyphen"

Tags: regex

I tried this but it doesn't work :

```
[^\s-]
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: @Marcelo The regex posted **works fine**. That was why I was asking. The only assumption I can make is that @rudimenter was expecting the class to repeat by default.

Comment: Yacoby, you should made that clear in the first place.

Comment: Hi rudimenter, can you please edit your question to clarify what you were actually asking?

Answer (score 159, accepted):

```
[^\s-]
```

should work and so will

```
[^-\s]
```

- `[]` : The char class
- `^` : Inside the char class `^` is the
  negator when it appears in the beginning.
- `\s` : short for a white space
- `-` : a literal hyphen. A hyphen is a
  meta char inside a char class but not
  when it appears in the beginning or
  at the end.

Comment: -(hyphen) should be escaped right ,since it is used for range. eg:-  [a-zA-Z]

Comment: @Aashiqahmed not when it appears in the beginning or at the end

Answer (score 92):

It can be done much easier:

`\S` which equals `[^ \t\r\n\v\f]`

Answer (score 10):

Which programming language are you using? May be you just need to escape the backslash like "[^\\s-]"

Comment: \s stands for whitespace
if you backslash the backslash it has an completly different meaning

Comment: @rudimenter: Cagdas was just suggesting that there might be different behavior depending on your environment (which you didn't tell us).

Comment: @rudimenter: If the regex is defined by a string, then you need to escape the backslash or use a verbatim string like `@"string"` in .NET or `r"string"` in Python.

Answer (score 8):

In Java:

```
    String regex = "[^-\\s]";

    System.out.println("-".matches(regex)); // prints "false"
    System.out.println(" ".matches(regex)); // prints "false"
    System.out.println("+".matches(regex)); // prints "true"
```

The regex `[^-\s]` works as expected. `[^\s-]` also works.

#### See also

- [Regular expressions and escaping special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399078/regular-expressions-and-escaping-special-characters)
- [regular-expressions.info/Character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

  - Metacharacters Inside Character Classes

    > The hyphen can be included right after the opening bracket, or right before the closing bracket, or right after the negating caret.

Comment: very strange
it works now with my original pattern
don't know what was wrong before

Answer (score 0):

Note that regex is not one standard, and each language implements its own based on what the library designers felt like. Take for instance the regex standard used by bash, documented here: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_05.
If you are having problems with regular expressions not working, it might be good to simplify it, for instance using "[^ -]" if this covers all forms of whitespace in your case.

Answer (score -6):

Try `[^- ]`, `\s` will match 5 other characters beside the space (like tab, newline, formfeed, carriage return).