# Checking for Whitespace in FluentValidation

Tags: c#, regex, fluentvalidation

I'm using FluentValidation and trying to create a rule that throws error if there is any whitespace in the string, i.e. for a username.

I've reviewed these SOs, but doesn't seem to work, I'm sure my syntax is off just a little?

[What is the Regular Expression For "Not Whitespace and Not a hyphen"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788112/what-is-the-regular-expression-for-not-whitespace-and-not-a-hyphen)
and 
[What is the Regular Expression For "Not Whitespace and Not a hyphen"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788112/what-is-the-regular-expression-for-not-whitespace-and-not-a-hyphen)

```
RuleFor(m => m.UserName).NotEmpty().Length(3, 15).Matches(@"/^\S\z/");
```

or

```
RuleFor(m => m.UserName).NotEmpty().Length(3, 15).Matches(@"[^\s]");
```

Neither of these seem to work. Other rules are not empty and between 3 and 15 characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just modifying your original rule a bit
**edit** Ok, removing delimiters as suggested.

```
RuleFor(m => m.UserName).NotEmpty().Length(3, 15).Matches(@"\A\S+\z");
```

All it does is force there to be non-whitespace in the whole string from start to finish.

Alternatively, I guess you could combine them into 1 match as in

```
RuleFor(m => m.UserName).Matches(@"\A\S{3,15}\z");
```

Comment: This works, except for the / and \ surrounding the expression. Remove those and either works. If you want to update the answer, I can mark it complete. Thanks! RuleFor(m => m.UserName).NotEmpty().Matches(@"\A\S{3,15}\z");

Comment: `RuleFor(m => m.UserName).NotEmpty().Matches(@"\A\S{3,15}\z"); ` not worked for me. It is showing validating even also when i am entering any characters

Comment: @AnmolRathod - `RuleFor(m => m.UserName).NotEmpty().Matches(@"\A\S{3,15}\z");  not worked for me. It is showing validating even also when i am entering any characters`  This ->  `\A` is absolute beginning of the string. `\z` is absolute end of string `\S{3,15}` is 3 to 15 _any character except whitespace_. And there you have it ..

Comment: @sln what would be final regex than ?

Comment: @AnmolRathod - The final regex was posted March 14, 2014.

Answer (score 3):

Try the char.IsWhiteSpace

```
RuleFor(m => m.UserName).NotEmpty().Length(3, 15).Must(userName => !userName.All(c => char.IsWhiteSpace(c)))
```

Comment: Was not able to get this to work. Also might there be a performance if using LINQ to check every character vs. the Regex approach.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me with **FluentValidation.MVC5** 6.4.0

```
RuleFor(x => x.username).Must(u => !u.Any(x => Char.IsWhiteSpace(x)));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
RuleFor(m => m.UserName).NotEmpty().Length(3, 15).Must (u => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(u));
```

Comment: That doesn't work. I'm still able to put whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static string RemoveWhitespace(this string input)
 {
    return new string(input.ToCharArray()
        .Where(c => !Char.IsWhiteSpace(c))
        .ToArray());
 }

RuleFor(x => x.Username).Must(s => s.Length == s.RemoveWhitespace().Length);
```