# Difference between \s and [:space:] in REGEXP_SUBSTR

Tags: regex, oracle

I try to extract the non-white space character from a string using REGEXP_SUBSTR.

I use this regex  `\s*([^\s]*)\s*` and extract the first group

Using `\s` to denote white spaces as documented
[here](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/ap_posix003.htm#SQLRF55544) removes the leading spaces, but preserves the training once.

```
 select  '"'||REGEXP_SUBSTR( ' xxx  ', '\s*([^\s]*)\s*', 1, 1, NULL, 1 )||'"' AS text
 from dual;

 "xxx  "
```

Only if I switch to the POSIX syntax as documented for [10g](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/ap_posix001.htm) I get the expected result.

```
 select  '"'||REGEXP_SUBSTR( ' xxx  ', '\s*([^[:space:]]*)[:space:]*', 1, 1, NULL, 1 )||'"' AS text
 from dual;

 "xxx"
```

What's (I'm doing) wrong?

I'm on 12.1.0.2.0

NLS_CHARACTERSET    WE8MSWIN1252

Comment: Have you checked this [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/ap_posix002.htm#SQLRF55542) ? Is says that `\` is not supported for multilingual enhancements.

Comment: `select  '"'||REGEXP_SUBSTR( ' xxx  ', '\s*(\S*)\s*', 1, 1, NULL, 1 )||'"' AS text from dual;`

Comment: @MTO thanks for the nice alternative, but the question was about the usage of \s in Nonmatching Character List. I was confused with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788112/what-is-the-regular-expression-for-not-whitespace-and-not-a-hyphen) accepted answer. It is simple wrong or some extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[^\s]` is incorrect, you can't use backslashed groups inside `[]`.

The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADFNS/adfns_regexp.htm#ADFNS1012) clearly states that

> In the list, all operators except these are treated as literals
>
> Range operator: -
>
> POSIX character class: [: :]
>
> POSIX collation element: [. .]
>
> POSIX character equivalence class: [= =]

So `\` mean it self inside `[]`

Comment: You can use `\s` inside `[]`.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber That is fine. The issue is that `[^\s]` actually matches everything except "\" and "s", i.e. including the remaining white space.

Comment: @Zbynek thank for the point, I'm trying to find a clarification in Oracle documentation, but no luck.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber: You should check this [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/ap_posix002.htm#SQLRF55542).

Comment: @Zbynek you are right +1. This  `select   REGEXP_SUBSTR( 'xxxssss', '([^\s]*).*', 1, 1, NULL, 1 )  AS text from dual` returns the xxx only. Anyway I thing this is specific to Oracle implementation, if so you may restrict your answer. I'll accept after a documentation link that clarify the behavior is provided.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber This is general behavior of regexp groups everywhere I have seen. The only special characters inside `[]` are just `[`, `]`, `-`.  Not sure about the link though...

Comment: @Zbynek [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788112/what-is-the-regular-expression-for-not-whitespace-and-not-a-hyphen) confused me. Probably some extension... I found in between the documentation and I'll add it to your answer and accept. Thanks for support!