# RegEx to find two words within one whole word

Tags: regex, full-text-search

Very simple, but I cannot get it to work.

I want to find two words inside a continous string (or one whole word)

**example**

Find me the two words - "student" and "name" only in whole strings (unseparated with whitespace or other words/chars)

So find it in these...

> "studentname"
>
> "studentpreferredname"
>
> "studentgivennames"
>
> "student_name"
>
> "student(*^&(*&(*&(*&&^*&^*&^*&^*&^%&^%name"

But not in these ...

> "**student** **name**"
>
> "**student**   [multiple spaces]    **name**"
>
> "**student** is their **name**"
>
> "the **student**'s **name** is"
>
> "A long time ago I wanted this **student** to have a similar **name**
>   to"

The only thing I can get to sort of work is regex:

> student.*name

But that brings in the cases above with all sorts of characters and words inbetween.

Thank you

**UPDATE**

See answer below.

This worked perfectly.

> \bstudent\S*name\b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dot in regular expressions `/./` is any character except a newline, that's why it doesn't work for you.

You probably need to use a **non-whitespace** character `/\S/`, which is a simpification of `/[^ \t\r\n\f]/`. Finally, your regex should look like this:

```
/student\S*name/
```

You can read more about **regular expressions in Ruby** in [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html).

Comment: Sorry I gave you kudos, but I've removed them. The above does not work. I am using grepWin and its Test regex feature. I've typed simple "studentname" and no match. I've tried "studentpreferredname" and again no match.

Comment: Actually it did work. I just needed to replace the '/' with '\b'

Comment: It's because I used `Ruby` syntax for Regex. I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to match with no space character between `student` and `name`.

If that is the case, try `student[^ ]*name`. `[^ ]` matches a character that is not a space.

Comment: No. Not just those with a space(s) in between. I want to find the words STUDENT and NAME inside a WHOLE word (string). Not those with words and spaces inbetween, if you know what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

This resolved it for me (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788112/what-is-the-regular-expression-for-not-whitespace-and-not-a-hyphen)).

> \bstudent\S*name\b