# how to check white space validation in my viewmodel.cs file in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, validation

i have a property in my EmployeeViewModel.cs as below

```
[Required]
[RegularExpeession]
public string EmpName {get;set;}
```

i am maintaining regex for not to allow special characters in my empName

when i give  whitespace(press space button 2 times) in my text box the RequiredField validation is not firing because it is considering whitespace as a value

how to check this whitespace issue using required attribue.

could some one help me

Comment: You can try settings this property of the `Required` attribute `AllowEmptyStrings` to `false`. More info here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute.allowemptystrings?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: AllowEmptyStrimg is not working here because whitespace is considering as a value

Answer (score 1):

You can add another validation to your model called [AllowEmptyStrings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute.allowemptystrings?view=netcore-3.1)

```
[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Please Provide Emp Name")]
[RegularExpeession]
public string EmpName {get;set;}
```

Comment: AllowEmptyString is not working here because whitespace is different from empty string

Answer (score 0):

This operation cannot be performed using: Required. I think you should use Regular Expression:

```
\S
```

which equals do a search for non-whitespace characters in a string.

Useful post and answer by: [engvard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1947073/engvard)

[What is the Regular Expression For “Not Whitespace and Not a hyphen”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2788112/what-is-the-regular-expression-for-not-whitespace-and-not-a-hyphen)